# PM2 error: app=npm id=0 does not have a pid

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, dockerfile, pm2

Having docker file contains following steps, image gets build successfully and if you check logs server also gets started successfully on the following port, but not sure facing this error from pm2 and pm2 gets stopped refer the logs.
So we deploy this using azure and through azure cli I can see deployment,services and pods getting created successfully.
**Once server starts and connection is made to mongo, all of sudden pm2 tries to kill pid and gets failed and eventually gets stopped**
Can someone help or point in right direction or cause of having this error

Docker file steps

```
FROM node:14.21.2-alpine
# Set the source folder
ARG SOURCE_FOLDER="./"

######################
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk update && apk add bash
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools

# Create the lscservices.sh for the services start command
RUN touch lscservices.sh && \
 chmod 700 lscservices.sh && \
 echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nlsc services start' > lscservices.sh && \
 mv lscservices.sh /usr/bin/
WORKDIR /labshare/communities-api
ARG NPM_TOKEN
COPY . .
# COPY package.json and project .
RUN echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > .npmrc
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp python3 make g++
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN rm -rf dist
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN rm package-lock.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm i pm2@latest -g
RUN npm i bash -g
RUN npm -g config set user root
RUN npm install @labshare/lsc -g
RUN npm install typescript -g
RUN npm run build
RUN rm -f .npmrc

# Run the service using pm2 and the shorcut to lsc start services
CMD ["pm2-docker","lscservices.sh"]
#CMD ["pm2-runtime", "npm", "start" ]
EXPOSE 8000
```

Logs:

```
2023-06-22T12:37:53: PM2 log: App [npm:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]stdout            
       2023-06-22T12:37:53: PM2 log: Script /usr/local/bin/npm had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"stdout
       2023-06-22T12:37:55: PM2 log: 0 application online, retry = 3 
 stdout
       2023-06-22T12:37:57: PM2 log: 0 application online, retry = 2 
 stdout
       2023-06-22T12:37:59: PM2 log: 0 application online, retry = 1 
 stdout
       2023-06-22T12:38:01: PM2 log: 0 application online, retry = 0 
stdout
2023-06-22T16:39:46.559Z info: LabShare services listening at http://:::8000  stdout
2023-06-22T12:38:01: PM2 log: Stopping app:npm id:0    stdout
2023-06-22T12:38:01: PM2 error: app=npm id=0 does not have a pid stderr
2023-06-22T12:38:01: PM2 log: PM2 successfully stopped stdout
2023-06-22T12:39:38: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode    stdout
2023-06-22T12:39:38: PM2 log: App [lscservices:0] starting in -fork mode-    stdout

2023-06-22T12:39:38: PM2 log: App [lscservices:0] online
```

things were fine and I am facing this error recently, we are using 14.2.1 alpine image for node, latest version for pm2

Comment: I saw pm2-runtime and visited how to gracefully stop pm2 and updated my pm2.json with increasing kill_timeout but still error persisits and due to this I get 502 bad gateway on my hosted environment

Answer (score 0):

For a NextJS setup, the same error, changing the `ecosystem.config.js` file from:

```
script: "./node_modules/.bin/next",
args: 'start',
```

to

```
script: "./node_modules/.bin/next start",
```

helped